# SharePoint - Remove/Hide 'Upload' option on specific document libraries

Tags: wss

On WSS, is there a method to disable the 'Upload' toolbar option on a document library level basis.

The reason for this is we want to force all new documents added to the library to be created by the 'New' option which forces them to use the most current template set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No** is unfortunately the correct answer as their is no permission setting that directly controls the upload functionality.

You could possibly develop your own custom template in code that disables this functionality but I have confirmed that on SharePoint 2010 this cannot be disabled either.